# Can anyone identify this freewheel type?

Tags: freewheel

When googling the types it seemed to most closely match a Atom/Regina but it has <s>25</s> 24 teeth and is about 3.5cm across. It's from a 1980s Raleigh road bike. But the bike has had a lot of work done to it so this part might not be original.

[image: Unidentified freewheel]

Thanks for any help

Comment: I'd suggest taking it to a bike shop to see if they have a matching tool.

Comment: I'd probably do [destructive freewheel removal](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/freewheel-destructive-removal). Probably easier than finding someone with the right tool or acquiring the right tool given you probably will never need it again.

Answer (score 3):

Clarification - I count 24 slots for a 24 spline removal tool, and not 25 as you state.

Jumping off from there I suspect you may have a Normandy/Maillard freewheel which takes a Bicycle Research Tools CT-3 24 spline freewheel removal tool.

Link to tool: http://www.bicycletool.com/normandymaillardfreewheeltool.aspx

Here's a link to the Bikeforums thread that lead me to the above link to the biketools website: http://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/604233-freewheel-removal-tool-older-simplex-design.html

Comment: Thanks for the help that looks like a good fit. I'll mark it as the correct answer when I try one (if I can track one down :)